# Redirect subdomain to Post URL

Tags: url-rewriting, apache2, subdomain

I want to redirect to my post URL when someone visits subdomain of that post name on my site.

Like this

> https://www.example.com/sub/mypost ---------> https://mypost.example.com

The site is running on Apache server

So have tried some changes to a .htaccess file

Please not everything is SSL

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} https://$1.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https://www.example.com/sub/$1" [L,P]

It did not seem working. it redirects to Site cant be reached message on browser.

This is my previos htaccess file before changes.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>



# END WordPress
```

Thank You.